# How do I get jQuery ajax url prefixes to resolve controller action methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm sure this question has been asked multiple times, but the one example of the problem I'm having was [asked about here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737094/how-do-i-get-the-correct-url-for-an-mvc-action-when-using-jquery-ajax)

Basically, if I have an ajax call to `/Controller/Action`, it works fine if I'm using my local development server of `localhost/Controller/Action`.

If I publish to UAT, the url needs more information. It's now `server/application/Controller/action`, which obviously breaks my ajax call.

`<%: Url.Action("MyAction") %>` solves this, but doesn't exist in the context of a seperate javascript file.

Currently, I have a javascript variable 'urlPrefix' in my app.js file, which I have to change between `""`and `"applicationName"` everytime I debug locally or release to a different server.

What's the easiest way of solving this?

Comment: One way is to add the url to the html element your handling, for example `<button data-url="@Url.Action("MyAction")" ...>` and then in the external js file - `$(myButton).click(function() { var url = $(this).data('url'); .... });` Another is to just add a variable the main view `var url = '@Url.Action(..)'; and access it from the external file.

Comment: i try with different methods, sometime one work another did not. '../SearchRole?prefix='   or 'SearchRole?prefix=' or '~/User/SearchRole?prefix=' + phrase

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
@Url.Content("~")
```

to resolve the root path of the application, so there'll be no need to change it between deployments.

One way to implement this is to add the following to your `<head>` in _layouts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var rootPath = '@Url.Content("~")';  // includes trailing /
</script>
```

(use your namespace as required)

then you can generate your actions such as:

```
var url = rootPath + 'controller/action/' + id
```